# Google Sheets Script Error When Trying to Copy Folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Problem 1:
When I try to execute the below code it comes up with the error 'Exception: Invalid argument: name (line 37, file "Create New Project")'. I originally thought that it could be that the variable 'jobNumber' wasn't a string but now that it is, it still doesn't execute.

Problem 2:
When I don't use the variable 'jobNumber' for the folder name and just us a string value, it executes. However the new folder does not go into the source folders drive but into my personal drive.

```
function createProject(){
 searchProject();
 createFolder();
 
}

//Search for New Project and return values
function searchProject(){
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var search = "New Job";
  
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i][9] == search){ 
      Logger.log((i+1));
      var jobNumber = sheet.getRange((i+1), 1).getDisplayValue()
      var jobSite = sheet.getRange((i+1), 2).getDisplayValue()
      var jobTitle = sheet.getRange((i+1), 3).getDisplayValue()
      return i+1;

    }
  }
  
}

//Create New Project Folders       
function createFolder(jobNumber, jobSite, jobTitle) {

  var sourceFolder = "12345_Site Name_Commissioning Engineer Name";
  var targetFolder = jobNumber
  var source = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolder);
  var target = DriveApp.createFolder(targetFolder);
  
  if (source.hasNext()) {
    copyFolder(source.next(), target);
  }
}

function copyFolder(source, target) {

  var folders = source.getFolders();
  var files   = source.getFiles();

  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
  }

  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = folders.next();
    var folderName = subFolder.getName();
    var targetFolder = target.createFolder(folderName);
    copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);
  }

}
```

Comment: By using '.getDisplayValue' I thought it was String

Comment: I suggest you to add a [mcve] including logging the cell value and data type (you might use `typeof`

Comment: Yeah you are correct, I have another function which is called from a ui Menu.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it looks that it's not valid anymore. I suggest you to update your question to show the current [mcve].

Comment: The way you are defining the `jobNumber` and using in the function is very confusing. You defined the variable inside the function, so it is in the scope of that function [not a global variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). About your second problem could please explain further what you want to do? Is the folder in your personal drive or in a shared one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find my own solution.
By adding the 'foler_ID' and 'folder' variable to get the folder to go into the correct folder in google drive.

I also missed calling the creatFolder function in searchProject function, with that now included the variables are carried over.

Thanks for all the contributors that helped :)

```
/**
 * Create New Project
 */ 

//Search for New Project and return values
function createProject(){
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var search = "New Job";
  
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i][9] == search){ 
      Logger.log((i+1));
      var jobNumber = sheet.getRange((i+1), 1).getDisplayValue()
      var jobSite = sheet.getRange((i+1), 2).getDisplayValue()
      var jobTitle = sheet.getRange((i+1), 3).getDisplayValue()
      
      createFolder (jobNumber, jobSite, jobTitle);
      
      Logger.log(jobNumber);
      Logger.log(jobSite);
      Logger.log(jobTitle);
      
      return i+1;
    }
  }
  
}

//Create New Project Folders       
function createFolder(jobNumber, jobSite, jobTitle) {

  var sourceFolder = "12345_Site Name_Commissioning Engineer Name";
  var targetFolder = (jobNumber + " " + jobSite + " " + jobTitle + "TESTING");
  var foler_ID = '14QpCYc803GnDC_pR-7AqViePHBKyNNv_';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(foler_ID);

  var source = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolder);
  var target = folder.createFolder(targetFolder);
  Logger.log(target);

  if (source.hasNext()) {
    copyFolder(source.next(), target);
  }
}

function copyFolder(source, target) {

  var folders = source.getFolders();
  var files   = source.getFiles();

  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
  }

  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = folders.next();
    var folderName = subFolder.getName();
    var targetFolder = target.createFolder(folderName);
    copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);
  }

}
```